# Optional Value eventEmitter Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, option-type

I was wondering (since google is not helping me right now). If it is possible to return an Optional value in an emit. I'm using EventEmitter In my angular project, and I want the value to be optional.

I could just slap a null in that value but it would feel slightly dirty, is there any way to make an optional value or would that require me to write an Abstract optional class?

Comment: To what `Optional` do you refer to? `new EventEmitter<T>()` requires a `T`  to be emitted https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/facade/src/async.ts#L113

Comment: I'm not refering to one, I'm saying I'm looking for an Optional solution. I am aware the EventEmitter is Generic. I'm looking for the actual value to be optional. so that T could be an User? or Optional<User> f/e if you compare it to other languages.

Comment: I guess you should add at least the typescript tag. This is a pure TypeScript question, not an Angular question. I don't use TypeScript myself and don't know such details.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense I wrote it early in the morning forgot that one ;-) thanks for the help anyhow